# How to change body's texture in matter

Tags: matter.js

I create a body like this:

```
Bodies.circle(x, y, 46, {
  render: {
    sprite: {
      texture: 'images/stone.png'
    }
  }
});
```

how can I to change the texture ?

Comment: Related: [How to change/update sprites textures in matterjs on clicking other object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487902/how-to-change-update-sprites-textures-in-matterjs-on-clicking-other-object). I recommend using a custom renderer.